# JQuery animate and slideUp simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-apps-script

I'm currently learning jQuery for a small project of mine and I want to do two actions simultaneously.
This doesn't work, so I'm guessing jQuery waits with animating the separator because it's still hidden.

Do any of you know a solution?

Code at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/onpgjk3L/5/

EDIT: I've updated it with Mogdad's guidelines in mind
  EDit: Another update to the fiddle: now toggleHelp *is*  being invoked (thanks Gerardo!)

PS: seems like toggleHelp() doesn't even get called in jsfiddle, although it certainly works on Google's servers (I'm using Google Apps Script btw)

```
-
```

Comment: "I'm using Google Apps Script" - no, you're not, at least not in your fiddle example.

Comment: Yes I do,' google.scripts.run.askRegister()' calls a function on Google's servers for example

Comment: I trust you understand that only works from Google's HTML service. Not from javascript in a jsFiddle. To improve your question, reduce the code to the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem. If it's a jQuery animation problem, then you don't need `google.scripts.run`. If it's a Google Apps Script problem, then include the GAS code that is involved.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me :) I have cleaned up the fiddle and now only the toggleHelp() function is present. What's strange is that toggleHelp() doesn't get invoked, although the image element has got an onClick attribute defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is strange that toggleHelp() is not being invoked. you can workaround it using jquery for setting the onclick event:

add an id to the img tag

```
 <img id="helpIcon" src="https://googledrive.com/host/0ByarjphAWhEvNFpCRmlPN0xRaFU/vraagteken">
```

and then with jquery in the javascript section:

```
$('#helpIcon').click(function(){
  toggleHelp();
});
```

Hope this helps.